# How to run subject after error happens in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Why `subject.next(2);` not works? I know it may happens because the signal stream got error.
But I add `catchError` and I return a `EMPTY` in the pipeline and it make it complete.

So seems `catchError` not helping me either.

How to make `subject.next(2)` works?

My code is calling to `doWork` function. inside I invoke `work` function. if it's one I simulate an error at the first time I call the function, after that should not have error.

Then I expose the subject and the subject-pipeline to do something else after the pipeline is invoked. I use `share` for that (to not duplicate my flow) and it should be happens only once.

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4wdsam?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

```
import { EMPTY, of, Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, share, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

const doWork = () => {
  const subject = new Subject();

  const work = (n) => {
    console.log('in work fn', n);
    if (n === 1) {
      throw new Error('bla');
    }
    return of([]);
  };

  const pipe = subject.pipe(
    exhaustMap((n) => work(n)),
    share()
  );

  pipe.subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('in subjectPipe next'),
    error: () => console.log('in subjectPipe error'),
    complete: () => console.log('in subjectPipe complete'),
  });

  return { subject, pipe };
};

const { subject, pipe } = doWork();

pipe
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('continue the pipe...'))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('in subject next'),
    error: () => console.log('in subject error'),
    complete: () => console.log('in subject complete'),
  });

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things here:

1. A `subject` which is a Subject
2. A `pipe` in the `doWork` function. Such `pipe` is actually a different object from `subject`. It is an Observable returned by the `pipe` function invoked on `subject`. `subject` is the source of `pipe`, but it is not `pipe`
3. `pipe` errors when processing the first notification, given the `work` function logic
4. A subscription to `pipe`

When an Observable errors, than it implicitly completes, so it will not notify any other value.

`pipe` errors immediately and therefore it will not notify any more, even if its source, which is `subject`, continues to notify.

Therefore you can do `subject.next(2)` but this notification will not be processed by `pipe` since `pipe` has already `error`ed.

There is one more thing. There is a `take(1)` in the bottom `pipe`. This means that we take the first notification and then we complete.

Therefore, even if you remove the logic the throws the error, you will not see a second `continue the pipe...` message printed on the console since the Observable completes after the first notification.

Answer (score 0):

I will extend on @Picci's answer:

To combat the fact, that when an emitter (`Subject` in this case) errors it cannot emit anymore, we can emit an `Error` instance instead. Handling such error will require more non-standard code, but it is definitely an easy to read solution to the given problem.